# Removing unnecessary numbers appended to postname in permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have, with help from Milo managed to tweak the permalinks for my custom post type so that they include the year and month of the event. e.g.

- `mysite.com/events/2013/january/fishing-trip`
- `mysite.com/events/2013/may/picnic`
- `mysite.com/events/2013/may/visit-grandma`

One small issue still evades me. If there is more than one event with the same name, WordPress appends a number to the end of the name even when the month is different and so there is no need for the name to be unique.

In other words I get

- `mysite.com/events/2013/january/fishing-trip`
- `mysite.com/events/2013/may/picnic`
- `mysite.com/events/2013/june/fishing-trip-2`

when I want

- `mysite.com/events/2013/january/fishing-trip`
- `mysite.com/events/2013/may/picnic`
- `mysite.com/events/2013/june/fishing-trip`

Is there a solution for this? I've got permalinks set to "postname" in permalink settings if this matters.

Comment: may want to include the code that Milo gave you?

Comment: Here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83531/custom-post-type-404s-with-rewriting-even-after-resetting-permalinks

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm interested as well. TIA

Comment: This is normal WP behaviour - there's not really a bug to fix. WP will append a number to any post with a duplicated name - regardless of the rest of the address.

Comment: A potential solution would be to use the month and year as part of the slug and drop it from the rewrites. It would ensure unique slugs and work around the issue you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for wordpress which allows you to handle 404 errors and redirect to specific pages. So if wordpress calls your post `/events/2013/june/fishing-trip-2`, you could go into the plugin and add a rule so that `/events/2013/june/fishing-trip` points to `/events/2013/june/fishing-trip-2`.

It's not a perfect solution, as you'd have to manually enter each duplicate post name to the rewrite rules, and even then the links wordpress generates for that post would still have the `-2`. You could write a function using preg_replace to then remove any -2 or -3 or whatever from the end of a link, but it's a little messy